# Thread, ansi c signal and Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals

I'm writing a multithread plugin based application. I will not be the plugins author. So I would wish to avoid that the main application crashes cause of a segmentation fault in a plugin. Is it possible? Or the crash in the plugin definitely compromise also the main application status?
I wrote a sketch program using qt cause my "real" application is strongly based on qt library. Like you can see I forced the thread to crash calling the trimmed function on a not-allocated QString. The signal handler is correctly called but after the thread is forced to quit also the main application crashes. Did I do something wrong? or like I said before what I'm trying to do is not achievable? 
Please note that in this simplified version of the program I avoided to use plugins but only thread. Introducing plugins will add a new critical level, I suppose. I want to go on step by step. And, overall, I want to understand if my target is feasible. Thanks a lot for any kind of help or suggestions everyone will try to give me.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QThread>
#include<csignal>
#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>


class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    static void sigHand(int sig)
    {
        qDebug("Thread crashed");
        QThread* th = QThread::currentThread();
        th->exit(1);
    }

    MyThread(QObject * parent = 0)
    :QThread(parent)
    {
        signal(SIGSEGV,sigHand);
    }

    ~MyThread()
    {
        signal(SIGSEGV,SIG_DFL);
        qDebug("Deleted thread, restored default signal handler");
    }

    void run()
    {
        QString* s;
        s->trimmed();
        qDebug("Should not reach this point");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyThread th(&a);
    th.run();
    while (th.isRunning());
    qDebug("Thread died but main application still on");
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently working on the same issue and found this question via google.

There are several reasons your source is not working:

- There is no new thread. The thread is only created, if you call QThread::start. Instead you call MyThread::run, which executes the run method in the main thread.
- You call QThread::exit to stop the thread, which is not supposed to directly stop a thread, but sends a (qt) signal to the thread event loop, requesting it to stop. Since there is neither a thread nor an event loop, the function has no effect. Even if you had called  QThread::start, it would not work, since writing a run method does not create a qt event loop. To be able to use exit with any QThread, you would need to call QThread::exec first.
  However, QThread::exit is the wrong method anyways. To prevent the SIGSEGV, the thread must be called immediately, not after receiving the (qt) signal in its event loop. So although generally frowned upon, in this case QThread::terminate has to be called
- But it is generally said to be unsafe to call complex functions like QThread::currentThread, QThread::exit or QThread::terminate from signal handlers, so  you should never call them there
- Since the thread is still running after the signal handler (and I'm not sure even QThread::terminate would kill it fast enough), the signal handler exits to where it was called from, so it reexecutes the instruction causing the SIGSEGV, and the next SIGSEGV occurs.

Therefore I have used a different approach, the signal handler changes the register containing the instruction address to another function, which will then be run, after the signal handler exits, instead the crashing instruction. Like:

```
void signalHandler(int type, siginfo_t * si, void* ccontext){
    (static_cast<ucontext_t*>(ccontext))->Eip = &recoverFromCrash;
}

struct sigaction sa;
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa)); sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sa.sa_sigaction = &signalHandler; 
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, 0);
```

The recoverFromCrash function is then normally called in the thread causing the SIGSEGV. Since the signal handler is called for all SIGSEGV, from all threads, the function has to check which thread it is running in.

However, I did not consider it safe to simply kill the thread, since there might be other stuff, depending on a running thread. So instead of killing it, I let it run in an endless loop (calling sleep to avoid wasting CPU time). Then, when the program is closed, it sets a global variabel, and the thread is terminated. (notice that the recover function must never return, since otherwise the execution will return to the function which caused the SIGSEGV)

Called from the mainthread on the other hand, it starts a new event loop, to let the program running.

```
if (QThread::currentThread() != QCoreApplication::instance()->thread()) {
    //sub thread
    QThread* t = QThread::currentThread();
    while (programIsRunning) ThreadBreaker::sleep(1);
    ThreadBreaker::forceTerminate();
} else {
    //main thread
    while (programIsRunning) {
        QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
        ThreadBreaker::msleep(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

ThreadBreaker is a trivial wrapper class around QThread, since msleep, sleep and setTerminationEnabled (which has to be called before terminate) of QThread are protected and could not be called from the recover function.

But this is only the basic picture. There are a lot of other things to worry about: Catching SIGFPE, Catching stack overflows (check the address of  the SIGSEGV, run the signal handler in an alternate stack), have a bunch of defines for platform independence (64 bit, arm, mac), show debug messages (try to get a stack trace, wonder why calling gdb for it crashes the X server, wonder why calling glibc backtrace for it crashes the program)...